# adding and accessing auxiliary tf.Dataset attributes with Keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow-datasets

I use a `tf.py_func` call to parse data (features, labels and sample_weights) from file to a `tf.Dataset`:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((records, labels, sample_weights))    
dataset = dataset.map(
   lambda filename, label, sample_weight: tuple(tf.py_func(
     self._my_parse_function, [filename, label, sample_weights], [tf.float32, label.dtype, tf.float32])))
```

The data is variable-length 1-D sequences, so I also pad the sequences to a fixed length in `my_parse_function`.

I use `tensorflow.python.keras.models.Sequential.fit(...)` to train the data (which now accepts datasets as input, including datasets with sample_weights) and `tensorflow.python.keras.models.Sequential.predict` to predict outputs.

Once I have predictions I would like to do some post-processing to make sense of the outputs. For example, I'd like to truncate the padded data to the actual sequence length. Also, I'd like to know for sure which file the data came from, since I am not sure that ordering is guaranteed with dataset iterators, especially if batching is used (I do batch the dataset as well) or multi-GPU or multi-workers are involved (I hope to try the multi- scenarios). Even if order was 'guaranteed' this is a decent sanity check.

This information, filename (i.e, a string) and sequence length (i.e, an integer), is not currently conveniently accessible, so I'd like to add these two attributes to the dataset elements and be able to retrieve them during/after the call to predict.

What is the best approach to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I store this auxiliary information in a 'global' dictionary in `my_parse_fn`, so it stores (and re-stores) on every iteration through the `tf.Dataset`.  This is ok for now since there are only about 1000 examples in the training set, so storing 1000 strings and integers is not a problem.  But if this auxiliary information were larger or the training set were larger, this approach would not be very scalable. In my case, the input data for each training example is significantly large, about 50MB in size, which is why reading a `tf.Dataset` from file (i.e., on every epoch) is important.

I still think that it would be helpful to be able to more conveniently extend a `tf.Dataset` with this information.  Also I noticed that when I adding a field to a `tf.Dataset` like dataset.tag to identify, say, dataset.tag = 'training', dataset.tag ='validation' or dataset.tag = 'test' sets, the field did not survive the iterations of training.

So again in this case I'm wondering how a `tf.Dataset` can be extended.

On the other question, it looks like the order of `tf.Dataset` elements **is** respected through iterations, so predictions, say, from `tensorflow.python.keras.models.Sequential.predict(...)` are ordered as the file ids were presented to `my_parse_fn` (at least batching respects this ordering, but I still don't know about whether a multi-GPU scenario would as well).

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: The order is deterministic if no dataset.shuffle() is called. See @mrry comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47781670/4095551

Comment: Hi! I am also struggling to add some sort of identifier to each tensor that indicates the image that it comes from, do you have additional information on how you implemented this workaround? Thanks!